# How to choose an item in <li> tag which is inside <ul> tag in HTML using VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="left: 353px; top: 400.21px; width: 251px; display: block; z-index: 12;">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-corner-all">S366</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-corner-all">S477</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-corner-all">S568</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
        <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-corner-all">S569</a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Using VBA I would like to select for example second option from above list, i.e. where the inner text is S477.

I have the following piece of code:

```
Set aTag = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each a in aTag
    If a.innerText = "S477" Then
        a.Click
    End If
Next
```

But it does not work. I searched many similar topics in the internet, but I did not find an answer.

Comment: Can you share an URL or more of the HTML please? Is it inside a form/iframe or frame tag? Also, what do you mean by does not work? Any error messages? And do you wish to select or click?

Comment: That HTML might be in "view source" but it's probably not the final form of the page - likely there's some script transforming it into a different structure: use your browser's Developer Tools to examine ho it really looks.